# common code to override fonts is not reflecting

Tags: android

```
 public static void overrideFont(Context context, String defaultFontNameToOverride, String customFontFileNameInAssets) {
    try {
        final Typeface customFontTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), customFontFileNameInAssets);

        final Field defaultFontTypefaceField = Typeface.class.getDeclaredField(defaultFontNameToOverride);
        defaultFontTypefaceField.setAccessible(true);
        defaultFontTypefaceField.set(null, customFontTypeface);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is my common code to override font in my fragment. I called this function in my fragment but it is not getting reflect my font was set to default . I dont know why this is happening .
Anyone has solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can not set font for one fragment or activity, so you need to set font for every field or for Application.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a class to apply font like this

```
public class SolomonTextView extends TextView {

    public SolomonTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public SolomonTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public SolomonTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),
                    "Solomon Sans.otf"); //setting font
            setTypeface(tf);
        }
    }
}
```

And use this class in your xml using full path of your file like this

```
 <yourpackage.SolomonTextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".6"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Match Summary"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />
```